# Connect to external HTTP server from Netty

Tags: http, nio, netty, router

I need some help with understanding how to write HTTP router, which recognizes HTTP header as routing criteria. I found the link https://github.com/cgbystrom/netty-tools/blob/master/src/main/java/se/cgbystrom/netty/http/router/RouterHandler.java which seems to do the routing itself. But now it is not clear, how to

- connect to another HTTP server
- send HTTP request
- wait for HTTP response
- forward the HTTP response to client

can somebody please give me some explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html

the example of proxy server in Netty, essentially what I wanted